# Iteration of cubic : could factorization be not unique?

Tags: polynomials, factoring

The plastic constant is solution of :

$$x^3=x+1\tag{1}$$

Considered over the reals.

Why iterating would give other solutions, since using : $x=x^3-1$ is a reversible function and so doesn't add extraneous solutions when substituted in $(1)$?

Then $$(x^3-1)^3=x^3$$ is a degree 9 polynomial.

Could it be that several triples $\{a,b,c\}$ are factorizing the first polynomial, $x^3=x+1$ ?

Comment: What are you iterating? And what is the "first polynomial" that you're referring to?

Comment: Thanks for the clarifications. Note that $x^3=x+1$ and $(x^3-1)^3=x^3$ are not polynomials, but rather equations. You can solve an equation, but you cannot factor one. So, to be more accurate while avoiding having to explicitly move everything over to the left-hand side, consider using phrasing like this: "Then $(x^3-1)^3=x^3$ *leads to* a degree $9$ polynomial."

Answer (score 1):

No.  The nine roots of the equation
$$
\big(x^3-1\big)^3=x^3
$$
are the three roots $\ r_1, r_2, r_3\ $ of the equation $\ x^3=x+1\ $ (only one of which is real) multiplied by the cube roots of unity, $\  1, \frac{-1+i\sqrt{3}}{2},\frac{-1-i\sqrt{3}}{2},\ $.  Of those nine roots, $\ r_1,r_2,r_3\ $ are the *only* ones that satisfy the original equation, $\ x^3=x+1\ $.